# While saving an image in my MVC WebApp, ModelState.IsValid always shows false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, entity-framework, model-view-controller

During Create, i always get the ModelState.IsValid as false and dont save my image in the database

In my model, the field for saving images is

```
[Required]
    public byte[] BookingImage { get; set; }
```

In my controller, I have the following code:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "BookingId,BookingName,BookingDescription,ProviderId,EmployeeId,StatusId,BookingDuration,BookingTime, BookingImage, BookingRequestAmount,BookingReserveDeadline")] Booking booking, HttpPostedFileBase BookingImageHidden)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BookingImageHidden.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                booking.BookingImage = ms.ToArray();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Booking.Add(booking);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.EmployeeId = new SelectList(db.Employee, "EmployeeId", "EmployeeName", booking.EmployeeId);
            ViewBag.ProviderId = new SelectList(db.Providers, "ProviderId", "ProviderName", booking.ProviderId);
            ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Status, "StatusId", "StatusName", booking.StatusId);
            return View(booking);
        }
```

In my View, this is the code around the Image:
@model Sword.Models.Booking

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "bookings", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))


{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Booking</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookingName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookingName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookingDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookingDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProviderId, "ProviderId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("ProviderId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProviderId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeId, "EmployeeId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("EmployeeId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusId, "StatusId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("StatusId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookingDuration, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingDuration, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookingDuration, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookingTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookingTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookingImage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingImage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                <input name="BookingImageHidden" type="file" />

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookingImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookingRequestAmount, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingRequestAmount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookingRequestAmount, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BookingReserveDeadline, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BookingReserveDeadline, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BookingReserveDeadline, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

> In my model, the field for saving images is [Required] public byte[]
>   BookingImage { get; set; }

Why do you even have a property in your model for the image if you are going to manually be reading it.

So simply consider using **view models** with the proper types (please notice that I am bolding the word view model here):

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
    [Required] 
    public HttpPostedFileBase BookingImage { get; set; }

    ... some other properties that you need populated from the client
}
```

and then in your controller action get rid of these hacks and use the view model:

```
public ActionResult Create(BookingViewModel bookingVm) 
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // In the MapFromViewModel you will obviously only
        // map the properties that you need to be populated
        // in your domain model from the view model. That's where
        // you should put the logic of reading the image stream into a 
        // byte array which is what your domain model expects.
        Booking booking = MapFromViewModel(bookingVm);
        db.Booking.Add(booking);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ...
}
```

You got into all those troubles because you didn't use view models in the first place but rather you had your controller actions take your domain models as parameter which is one of the worst MVC design patterns I have ever seen in my life.